# ANTLR4 notifyErrorListeners

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

As a newbie to ANTLR, I ran into a problem:
my grammar includes

```
COMMENT :   ( '*' {getCharPositionInLine()==0}? .* NL
             | '*' {getCharPositionInLine()>0}? .* NL {System.out.println("* at wrong position"); notifyListeners("xxx");}
 );
```

meaning I want to check whether a line start with a * (OK) or whether the * is in another position (Error).

In IntelliJ IDEA, I get the following compile error:

```
 Error:(106, 68) java: cannot find symbol
   symbol:   method notifyErrorListeners(java.lang.String)
   location: class MQSC.MQSCLexer
```

As this seems to be the solution as described in the book "The definitive ANTLR4 reference", I am stuck. Is this the right way, do I miss something?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue following my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you need ANTLR Java Runtime dependency in your classpath, for a Maven project that would be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise download [antlr-runtime-4.6.jar](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-runtime-4.6.jar) and add  it to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).